# Masonry layout not centering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-masonry, masonry

I implemented a masonry layout but the div classes are not centering in the middle of the screen. 4 classes across the screen centered left and right width have to be the same. Im trying to center it perfectly in the middle of the wrapper div tag. Thanks for helping. Check my website live : [www.problemsofnewyork.com/test.php](http://www.problemsofnewyork.com/test.php)

index.php

```
   <?php include_once('php/db.php'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/test.css"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://desandro.github.io/masonry/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="grid">
            <?php 
                $result = $db -> prepare ("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");
                $result->execute();

                while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $content = $row['content'];
                    $image = $row['image'];
                    $posted_by = $row['posted'];

                    echo "
                    <div class='grid-item'>
                        <img src='images/".$image."'/>
                        <b>".$title."</b>
                        <p>".$id.") ". $content ."</p>
                        <span>Posted by: <i>".$posted_by."</i></span>
                    </div>
                    ";

                }
            ?>
        </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        $('.grid').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.grid-item'
        });
        var $container = $('.grid');
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
          $container.masonry({
            itemSelector : '.grid-item'
          });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the css

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body {
    background: #e9e9e9;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 auto
}
.grid {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 15px auto;
}
.grid-item {
    width: 340px;
    background: #fff;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.22);
}
.grid-item b {
    padding: 5px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.grid-item p {
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 13px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.grid-item span {
    float: right;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: monospace;
}
.grid-item img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: this question had nothing to do with php

Comment: Please remove all PHP from your question because it isn't relevant. Instead please post the HTML for a [Short, Self Contained, Correct, Example](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Adding `isFitWidth: true` did the trick.

This code :

```
<script>
    $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item'
    });
    var $container = $('.grid');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.grid-item'
      });
    });
</script>
```

to this :

```
<script>
    $('.grid').masonry({
      itemSelector: '.grid-item'
    });
    var $container = $('.grid');
    $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector : '.grid-item',
        isFitWidth: true
      });
    });
</script>
```